# how to efficiently split a large dataframe into many parquet files?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

Consider the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow as pa

idx = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 12:00:00.000', '2017-03-01 12:00:00.000', freq = 'T')

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'numeric_col' : np.random.rand(len(idx)),
                          'string_col' : pd.util.testing.rands_array(8,len(idx))},
                           index = idx)

dataframe
Out[30]: 
                     numeric_col string_col
2017-01-01 12:00:00       0.4069   wWw62tq6
2017-01-01 12:01:00       0.2050   SleB4f6K
2017-01-01 12:02:00       0.5180   cXBvEXdh
2017-01-01 12:03:00       0.3069   r9kYsJQC
2017-01-01 12:04:00       0.3571   F2JjUGgO
2017-01-01 12:05:00       0.3170   8FPC4Pgz
2017-01-01 12:06:00       0.9454   ybeNnZGV
2017-01-01 12:07:00       0.3353   zSLtYPWF
2017-01-01 12:08:00       0.8510   tDZJrdMM
2017-01-01 12:09:00       0.4948   S1Rm2Sqb
2017-01-01 12:10:00       0.0279   TKtmys86
2017-01-01 12:11:00       0.5709   ww0Pe1cf
2017-01-01 12:12:00       0.8274   b07wKPsR
2017-01-01 12:13:00       0.3848   9vKTq3M3
2017-01-01 12:14:00       0.6579   crYxFvlI
2017-01-01 12:15:00       0.6568   yGUnCW6n
```

I need to write this dataframe into many parquet files. Of course, the following works:

```
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(dataframe)
pq.write_table(table, '\\\\mypath\\dataframe.parquet', flavor ='spark')
```

My issue is that the resulting (single) `parquet` file gets too big.

How can I efficiently (memory-wise, speed-wise) *split the writing* into `daily` parquet files (and keep the `spark` flavor)? These daily files will be easier to read in parallel with `spark` later on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Making a string column`dt` based off of the index will then allow you to write out the data partitioned by date by running

```
pq.write_to_dataset(table, root_path='dataset_name', partition_cols=['dt'], flavor ='spark')
```

Answer is based off of this [source](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html?highlight=pyarrow%20parquet%20partition#writing-to-partitioned-datasets) (note, the source incorrectly lists the partition argument as `partition_columns`)

Comment: you mean first creating `dataframe['dt'] = dataframe.index.date`
 ?

Comment: I get `TypeError: __cinit__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partition_columns'`

Comment: The partitioned column will have to be a string, eg `2017-01-01`, but that doesn't seem to be the problem that the error is pointing to. Does it work if you drop the `flavor ='spark'` option?

Comment: It does not, I actually have used `dataframe['dt'] = dataframe.index.date.astype(str)
`. I am using `the root_path` as `C://myfolder/` is that ok?

Comment: Looks like the keyword argument is `partition_cols` not `partition_columns`. I updated the answer and confirmed it works locally

Comment: really cool! I wonder if there is the equivalent of parquet `pyarrow` in R. right now I am loading that stuff using `sparklyr`, but could we load these `parquet` files in a regular R session? its a mystery. Thanks anyway! great catch

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I found it extremely slow. Any chance to use dask for it?

Comment: huuum... I have not tried with my big dataset yet. let me do some testing

Comment: yeah that fails pretty miserably on my 100m obs data... sob sob

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I gave a try with dask (as I used it before to split a dataframe in different parquets) but fot this particular case got an  issue see https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3598.

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I partially solved the problem with dask https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3598#issuecomment-396970081
To save a df with about 10M rows take less than 20 seconds on my machine.
Now it will be interesting to see if we can set `flavor='spark'` and name the files accordingly.

Comment: @user32185 yes, that is interesting. I am really looking forward to a spark flavored solution here. perhaps you can chime in here as well? https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/2138

Answer (score 2):

The solution presented by David doesn't solve the problem as it generates a parquet file for every index. But this slight modified version does the trick

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow as pa
idx = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 12:00:00.000', '2017-03-01 12:00:00.000',
                    freq='T')

df = pd.DataFrame({'numeric_col': np.random.rand(len(idx)),
                   'string_col': pd.util.testing.rands_array(8,len(idx))},
                  index = idx)

df["dt"] = df.index
df["dt"] = df["dt"].dt.date
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_to_dataset(table, root_path='dataset_name', partition_cols=['dt'], 
                    flavor='spark')
```

Comment: I think he was suggesting the same thing. the issue is to make it work with a very large dataframe...

Comment: Yes but in that case you saved a file for each index now it's a file for every day. If you try this example from 1998-01-01 (which is more than 10M rows) you can save it in about 40 seconds.

Comment: interesting but this is actually what i did with my large dataframe and ending up with memory issues... i set dt as index.date.astype(str)

Comment: I think that this is the problem. All the time you use `object` or `string` instead of numeric/datatime you're going to use more memory. Try to give it a try without change type.